# How to format lists in pandoc-generated docx documents?

Tags: docx, pandoc

I am using pandoc 2.7.2 to generate a docx from markdown.  The target docx format relies on funny indentation depths.  Thus, I am using a hand-crafted reference.docx, which works just fine for most paragraph styles.

One exception are lists created by pandoc.  I am not able to determine the style pandoc is using for lists and thus, I do not know, how to update my reference.docx, so that lists are properly indented or if there possibly is another way to customise list formats for pandoc-generated documents.  Any help appreciated, TIA.

Comment: maybe try asking on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss

Comment: Thanks, I'll do.

Comment: Just for  the record, I promptly got the information I needed there, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/bvfGy_VVwEE/dbuD0f1ZAgAJ.